# SQL Joining the first, second and third row of joining table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I need to display some columns on the final result which comes from a join. Those columns comes in 3 groups, say:

```
name_1, addr_1, prefecture_1, price_1,
name_2, addr_2, prefecture_2, price_2,
name_3, addr_3, prefecture_3, price_3
```

Where these 3 groups comes from a join which should return only 3 records according to a sort key **carrier_cd2**.  The _1 group is the first row, _2 group the second and _3 is the third row.

My question is pretty much the same as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629183/sql-query-join-that-returns-the-first-two-records-of-joining-table) but I need 3 records instead of 2.

I have come up with my initial SQL query:

```
SELECT
    inner_t12.contract_no,
    inner_t13.carrier_cd2,
    inner_t13.addr,
    inner_t13.prefecture,
    inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2,
    inner_t13_2.addr,
    inner_t13_2.prefecture,
    inner_t13_3.carrier_cd2,
    inner_t13_3.addr,
    inner_t13_3.prefecture
FROM
    処分業者契約マスタ inner_t12
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ inner_t13
        ON inner_t12.contract_no = inner_t13.contract_no
    JOIN 処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ inner_t13_2
        ON inner_t13_2.contract_no = inner_t13.contract_no
        AND inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2 > inner_t13.carrier_cd2
    JOIN 処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ inner_t13_3
        ON inner_t13_3.contract_no = inner_t13.contract_no
        AND inner_t13_3.carrier_cd2 > inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2
```

[The screenshot](http://picasaweb.google.com/dc.eros/RandomImages#5533320707180255074)

It returns the required rows on the final result set, however it need to be left outer join so that it will still display rows even if the join does not produce the required 3 rows, even 2 or 1 or none should work and display NULL instead.

Hope you can give some hints on this.

SQL Server 2005 Express

Comment: @mahesh, I'm sorry but I don't get what you say. Are you saying that I need to change this post into some language category? Am I posting on wrong category?

Comment: mahesh means you have to format your post neatly(remove those 委委委委委, chinese characters right?)

Comment: No, they are table names. (Japanese) Maybe mahesh means that I need to set the code to SQL to allow syntax highlighting. I don't know how. I'm trying for format my post neatly and that is all I got so far :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved it (sort of). What I did was use ROW_NUMBER and OVER() on the ON clause of a JOIN.

```
use OurProjectDb
go

SELECT
    t12.disposal_cd,

    t21_1.name_kanji AS name_kanji_1,
    t13_1.prefecture AS prefecture_1,
    t13_1.addr AS addr_1,
    t13_1.permission_no AS permission_no_1,
    t13_1.vehicle_type AS vehicle_type_1,
    t13_1.transport_price AS transport_price_1,

    t21_2.name_kanji AS name_kanji_2,
    t13_2.prefecture AS prefecture_2,
    t13_2.addr AS addr_2,
    t13_2.permission_no AS permission_no_2,
    t13_2.vehicle_type AS vehicle_type_2,
    t13_2.transport_price AS transport_price_2,

    t21_3.name_kanji AS name_kanji_3,
    t13_3.prefecture AS prefecture_3,
    t13_3.addr AS addr_3,
    t13_3.permission_no AS permission_no_3,
    t13_3.vehicle_type AS vehicle_type_3,
    t13_3.transport_price AS transport_price_3
FROM
    処分業者契約マスタ t12
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ t13_1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 委託運搬業者マスタ t21_1 ON t13_1.carrier_cd2 = t21_1.carrier_cd2
    )
    ON t13_1.contract_no = t12.contract_no AND t13_1.carrier_cd2 = (
        SELECT TOP 1
            inner_t13_1.carrier_cd2
        FROM
            処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ inner_t13_1
        WHERE
            inner_t13_1.contract_no = t12.contract_no
        ORDER BY
            inner_t13_1.carrier_cd2 ASC
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ t13_2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 委託運搬業者マスタ t21_2 ON t13_2.carrier_cd2 = t21_2.carrier_cd2
    )
    ON t13_2.contract_no = t12.contract_no AND t13_2.carrier_cd2 = (
        SELECT
            carrier_cd2
        FROM
        (
            SELECT TOP 2
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2) AS row_num,
                inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2
            FROM
                処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ inner_t13_2
            WHERE
                inner_t13_2.contract_no = t12.contract_no
            ORDER BY
                inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2
        ) top2join
        WHERE
            row_num = 2
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ t13_3
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 委託運搬業者マスタ t21_3 ON t13_3.carrier_cd2 = t21_3.carrier_cd2
    )
    ON t13_3.contract_no = t12.contract_no AND t13_3.carrier_cd2 = (
        SELECT
            carrier_cd2
        FROM
        (
            SELECT TOP 3
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY inner_t13_3.carrier_cd2) AS row_num,
                inner_t13_3.carrier_cd2
            FROM
                処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ inner_t13_3
            WHERE
                inner_t13_3.contract_no = t12.contract_no
            ORDER BY
                inner_t13_3.carrier_cd2
        ) top3join
        WHERE
            row_num = 3
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question I think you're looking for this. Bracket the two inner joins inside the left join

```
FROM
    inner_t12
    LEFT OUTER JOIN inner_t13
    (    
    INNER JOIN  inner_t13_2
        ON inner_t13_2.contract_no = inner_t13.contract_no
        AND inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2 > inner_t13.carrier_cd2
    INNER JOIN  inner_t13_3
        ON inner_t13_3.contract_no = inner_t13.contract_no
        AND inner_t13_3.carrier_cd2 > inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2
)
ON inner_t12.contract_no = inner_t13.contract_no
```

Comment: With that I got this: http://lysender.pastebin.com/VqbhH2jk but there was an error: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 75
キーワード 'INNER' 付近に不適切な構文があります。- Which means there was a syntax error near INNER. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I got it, the open parenthesis must be after the LEFT OUTER JOIN keyword and before the table name. That technique helps a lot but not as overall solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just 3 rows (3 records),
Just add "`TOP 3`" in your `SELECT` statement.
See below.

```
SELECT
    TOP 3
    inner_t12.contract_no,
    inner_t13.carrier_cd2,
    inner_t13.addr,
    inner_t13.prefecture,
    inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2,
    inner_t13_2.addr,
    inner_t13_2.prefecture,
    inner_t13_3.carrier_cd2,
    inner_t13_3.addr,
    inner_t13_3.prefecture
FROM
    処分業者契約マスタ inner_t12
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ inner_t13
        ON inner_t12.contract_no = inner_t13.contract_no
    JOIN 処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ inner_t13_2
        ON inner_t13_2.contract_no = inner_t13.contract_no
        AND inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2 > inner_t13.carrier_cd2
    JOIN 処分契約委託運搬業者マスタ inner_t13_3
        ON inner_t13_3.contract_no = inner_t13.contract_no
        AND inner_t13_3.carrier_cd2 > inner_t13_2.carrier_cd2
```

Comment: No its not. I need to distribute those top 3 rows as columns on the final result set. I've done that using sub query in select but it does not pass the QC :D